# How to validate URL using Regular expression with query string?

Tags: c#, regex, validation

Please do read full question before marking it duplicate.

I want to validate URL which can contain query string. I found some of the solutions. But It is not working for me. 
Examples of valid URLs for me are:
1)http://www.example.com/
2)www.example.com
3)example.com
4)http://www.exaple.com/test2/aa.aspx?id=2&sad=ss

I have used following expression:
1) `^((http|https)://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w]+(/[\w- ./?]*)?$`

But when I used this expression Query string were not allowed.

2) `(http|ftp|https)://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?`
But in this `http` is required. If i enter URL like: `google.com` this expression says it is not valid.

Can anyone help me to validate this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try Uri.[TryCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.trycreate.aspx) to validate the uri.

Comment: Even the most basic regex knowledge should let you change your second expression to make the protocol identifier optional...

Comment: I want to validate URL on textbox using validator. I don't have other option right now. I need the expression which can help me. I dont have access to back hand code.

Comment: I tried but it is not helping me.

Comment: Well, it might be a duplicate.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url

Comment: Your second query is good. Not sure why you cannot modify it to suit your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below expression worked for me. Please try this:

```
^((http|https|ftp|www):\/\/)?([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)(\.)([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]+)
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try the below expression and let me know the result

```
((http|ftp|https):\//(www)\.{0,}){0,}\w*\.\w{3}((\/\w*){1,}\.\w*\?{1}(\w*\=\w*){0,}\&{0,}(\w*\=\w*){0,}){0,}
```

Comment: It matches `http://wwwhttp://wwww.fff`, for a start. And `.www`. And `.www/.?&&&&&&`.